# Error al realizar consulta con pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Al realizar la consulta me genera un error el cual dice que no me reconoce el nombre de la columna `t1.codigo` ni el nombre de la columna `t1.examen`:

> el identificador formado por varias partes T2.CODIGO , no se pudo
>   enlazar

he revisado la sintaxis y no doy. Alguna ayuda por favor.

este es el código

```
   SELECT  GENPACIEN.PACNUMDOC AS DOCUMENTO_PACIENTE, 
GENPACIEN.PACPRINOM + ' ' + GENPACIEN.PACSEGNOM + ' ' + GENPACIEN.PACPRIAPE + ' ' + GENPACIEN.PACSEGAPE AS NOMBRES,
ADNINGRESO.AINCONSEC AS INGRESO,
T1.[SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  1.], 
T1.[SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  2.],
T1.[SIFILIS SEROLOGIA PRESUNTIVA (CARDIOLIPINA O VDRL)],
T1.[VIH 1 Y 2  ANTICUERPOS]
FROM GENPACIEN
INNER JOIN ADNINGRESO
ON ADNINGRESO.GENPACIEN = GENPACIEN.OID
INNER JOIN HCNSOLEXA
ON HCNSOLEXA.ADNINGRESO= ADNINGRESO.OID
INNER JOIN 

(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT GENSERIPS.SIPNOMBRE AS EXAMEN, GENSERIPS.OID AS CODIGO  FROM GENSERIPS WHERE  GENSERIPS.OID IN(1631,1626,1627,7457)) AS T2
PIVOT( SUM (CODIGO) FOR EXAMEN IN( [SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  1.], [SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  2.], [SIFILIS SEROLOGIA PRESUNTIVA (CARDIOLIPINA O VDRL)], [VIH 1 Y 2  ANTICUERPOS] )  ) AS PIVOTEXAMEN 
) AS T1
ON  T2.CODIGO = HCNSOLEXA.GENSERIPS
INNER JOIN HCNFOLIO
ON HCNFOLIO.GENPACIEN = GENPACIEN.OID
INNER JOIN HCMAIEPI
ON HCMAIEPI.HCNFOLIO = HCNFOLIO.OID
WHERE ADNINGRESO.AINFECING >='01-05-2018 00:00:00.00' AND  ADNINGRESO.AINFECING < '01-06-2018 00:00:00.00'  
GROUP BY T2.EXAMEN  ,ADNINGRESO.AINCONSEC,GENPACIEN.PACNUMDOC, GENPACIEN.PACPRINOM , GENPACIEN.PACSEGNOM , GENPACIEN.PACPRIAPE , GENPACIEN.PACSEGAPE
ORDER BY 3 ASC
```

Comment: cual es el error que arroja el motor?

Comment: el error que me arroja el motor es el siguiente : " el identificador  formado por varias partes T2.CODIGO , no se pudo enlazar"

Comment: según lo que recuerdo el campo que vas a utilizar como pivot no puede ser un alias

Comment: Por favor, incluye la descripción de las tablas usadas en la consulta COMO TEXTO (no como imagen). Y los mensajes de error se ponen, tal cual los encuentras, dentro de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya logre el codigo, gracias.

```
SELECT  GENPACIEN.PACNUMDOC AS DOCUMENTO_PACIENTE, 
GENPACIEN.PACPRINOM + ' ' + GENPACIEN.PACSEGNOM + ' ' + GENPACIEN.PACPRIAPE + ' ' + GENPACIEN.PACSEGAPE AS NOMBRES,
ADNINGRESO.AINCONSEC,
T2.[SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  1.],
T2.[SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  2.],
T2.[SIFILIS SEROLOGIA PRESUNTIVA (CARDIOLIPINA O VDRL)],
T2.[VIH 1 Y 2  ANTICUERPOS]
FROM GENPACIEN
INNER JOIN ADNINGRESO
ON ADNINGRESO.GENPACIEN = GENPACIEN.OID
INNER JOIN 


(SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT HCNSOLEXA.HCSCANTI AS CANTIDAD ,GENSERIPS.SIPNOMBRE AS EXAMEN_PACIENTE,HCNSOLEXA.ADNINGRESO AS INGRESO2 FROM 
HCNSOLEXA INNER JOIN GENSERIPS
ON HCNSOLEXA.GENSERIPS= GENSERIPS.OID
WHERE GENSERIPS.OID IN (1631,1626,1627,7457)
) AS T1


PIVOT 
(
COUNT(CANTIDAD) FOR EXAMEN_PACIENTE IN ([SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  1.],[SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  2.],[SIFILIS SEROLOGIA PRESUNTIVA (CARDIOLIPINA O VDRL)],[VIH 1 Y 2  ANTICUERPOS])
) AS PV


)T2

ON T2.INGRESO2= ADNINGRESO.OID
INNER JOIN HCNFOLIO
ON HCNFOLIO.GENPACIEN = GENPACIEN.OID
INNER JOIN HCMAIEPI
ON HCMAIEPI.HCNFOLIO = HCNFOLIO.OID
WHERE ADNINGRESO.AINFECING >='01-05-2018 00:00:00.00' AND  ADNINGRESO.AINFECING < '01-06-2018 00:00:00.00'
GROUP BY T2.[SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  1.],
T2.[SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  2.],
T2.[SIFILIS SEROLOGIA PRESUNTIVA (CARDIOLIPINA O VDRL)],
T2.[VIH 1 Y 2  ANTICUERPOS],ADNINGRESO.AINCONSEC,GENPACIEN.PACNUMDOC, GENPACIEN.PACPRINOM , GENPACIEN.PACSEGNOM , GENPACIEN.PACPRIAPE , GENPACIEN.PACSEGAPE
ORDER BY 3 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con en esto (reemplaza estas lineas), y me comentas, lo mas probable es que el error se encuentre porque estas intentando relacionar un Alias o una ruta a la cual no estas llegando:

```
  (SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT GENSERIPS.SIPNOMBRE AS EXAMEN, GENSERIPS.OID AS CODIGO  FROM 
  GENSERIPS WHERE  GENSERIPS.OID IN(1631,1626,1627,7457)) T2
  PIVOT( SUM (GENSERIPS.OID) FOR EXAMEN IN( [SIDA ANTICUERPOS VIH  1.], [SIDA 
  ANTICUERPOS VIH  2.], [SIFILIS SEROLOGIA PRESUNTIVA (CARDIOLIPINA O VDRL)], 
  [VIH 1 Y 2  ANTICUERPOS] )  ) AS PIVOTEXAMEN 
  )  T1
  ON  T1.T2.GENSERIPS.OID = HCNSOLEXA.GENSERIPS
```

Comment: Nada Francisco. aun sale ese error

Comment: prueba de nuevo con el código que edite arriba

Comment: nada hermano sigue igual.

Comment: intenta de nuevo porfa con el código editado

Comment: pienso que no esta llegando al enlace 'T2.GENSERIPS.OID' o 'T2.CODIGO', debido a que T2 esta dentro de T1, y el llamado lo haces directo a T2 saltandote T1, pienso que por eso no esta llegando al enlace.